# How to use boolean 'and' in Python

Tags: python, boolean-logic

In C# we can use `&&` (boolean and) like this:

```
int i = 5;
int ii = 10;
if(i == 5 && ii == 10) {
    Console.WriteLine("i is 5, and ii is 10");
}
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

But try that with python:

```
i = 5
ii = 10
if i == 5 && ii == 10:
    print "i is 5 and ii is 10";
```

I get an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

If I use a single `&`, at least I get no syntax error.  How do I do a boolean `&&` in Python?

Answer (score 76):

Try this:

```
i = 5
ii = 10
if i == 5 and ii == 10:
      print "i is 5 and ii is 10"
```

**Edit**: Oh, and you dont need that semicolon on the last line (edit to remove it from my code).

Comment: The semicolon is useful if we want to combine lines of codes.

Comment: Combining lines is not the "pythonic" way though

Comment: Although you can combine lines, as Rodrigo says, its not "pythonic".  Since in this particular case the semicolon had no effect at all I made a comment about its redundancy. I assumed the questioner was new to python and didnt want to bloat my answer as to what is "pythonic" and what semicolon does.

Answer (score 29):

As pointed out, "&" in python performs a bitwise and operation, just as it does in C#. `and` is the appropriate equivalent to the `&&` operator.

Since we're dealing with booleans (`i == 5` is `True` and `ii == 10` is also `True`), you may wonder why this didn't either work anyway (True being treated as an integer quantity should still mean True & True is a True value), or throw an exception (eg. by forbidding bitwise operations on boolean types)

The reason is operator precedence.  The "`and`" operator binds more loosely than `==`, so the expression:    "`i==5 and ii==10`" is equivalent to: "`(i==5) and (ii==10)`"

However, bitwise `&` has a higher precedence than "`==`" (since you wouldn't want expressions like "`a & 0xff == ch`" to mean "`a & (0xff == ch)`"), so the expression would actually be interpreted as:

```
if i == (5 & ii) == 10:
```

Which is using python's operator chaining to mean: does the valuee of ii anded with 5 equal both i and 10.  Obviously this will never be true.

You would actually get (seemingly) the right answer if you had included brackets to force the precedence, so:

```
if (i==5) & (ii=10)
```

would cause the statement to be printed.  It's the wrong thing to do, however - "`&`" has many different semantics to "`and`" - (precedence, short-cirtuiting, behaviour with integer arguments etc), so it's fortunate that you caught this here rather than being fooled till it produced less obvious bugs.

Answer (score 16):

The correct operator to be used are the keywords 'or' and 'and', which in your example, the correct way to express this would be:

```
if i == 5 and ii == 10:
    print "i is 5 and ii is 10"
```

You can refer the details in the ["Boolean Operations" section in the language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Comment: Whenever I see `and`, I reahc for my parentheses

Answer (score 7):

You can also test them as a couple.

```
if (i,ii)==(5,10):
    print "i is 5 and ii is 10"
```

Comment: The pedant in me wants to point out that you ought to say "tuple" instead of "couple" but I know what you meant. :)

Comment: A couple is not a tuple?

Answer (score 6):

`&` is used for bit-wise comparison. use `and` instead. and btw, you don't need semicolon at the end of print statement.

Answer (score 6):

In python, use `and` instead of `&&` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
foo = True;
bar = True;
if foo and bar:
    print "both are true";
```

This prints:

```
both are true
```

Comment: More precisely we spell "&&" as "and".  We spell "&" as "&" as in both C# and python these perform a bitwise, rather than logical, and operation.

Comment: You are right, of course. Apologies.