# Having trouble using <= with "elif" and "and"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Learning Python using a textbook and codecademy.

This code is returning a SyntaxError. Can I not use two greater/less than symbols in the same elif statement? Or is the problem my '<='?

```
def movie_rating(rating):
    if rating <= 5:
        return "Avoid"
    elif rating > 5 and <= 9:
        return "I recommend!"
    else:
        return "Amazing"
```

Comment: `elif rating > 5 and rating <= 9:`  The problem is that `<=` needs something on the left side to compare to. we need to be explicit that we want **`rating`** less than equal to 9.

Comment: First issue is indentation. Fix that.

Comment: `elif 5 < rating <= 9:`

Comment: @spencer7593 - thank you so much much! Such a simple mistake I completely overlooked.

Comment: in this context, we've already done the check of `rating <= 5`, so if we fall into the `elif`, we don't need to confirm that rating is greater than 5. That is, we will get the same result with just **`elif rating <= 9:`**  (And this is a better way to do the range check, in case we decide to change our Avoid rating to be less than or equal to 4, we only have to change the 5 to a 4 in one place. (If we don't want a rating of 5 to fall through to 'Amazing'.)

Comment: Oh, I see! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me and giving me a better understanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of your `and` in line 4, this error happening because when you use and you need to define a new condition in other word you should change your code to one of this codes:

```
def movie_rating(rating):
    if rating <= 5:
        return "Avoid"
    elif rating > 5 and rating <= 9:
        return "I recommend!"
    else:
        return "Amazing"
```

or change your code to this:

```
def movie_rating(rating):
    if rating <= 5:
        return "Avoid"
    elif 5> rating <= 9:
        return "I recommend!"
    else:
        return "Amazing"
```

if you want to know how you can use `and` in python, follow this link:

[How to use boolean 'and' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609972/how-to-use-boolean-and-in-python)
and
[how use if and else elif or](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/9-else-and-or-not/)

Comment: oh yes your right, sorry, that was unwanted. now I changed my answer,
and its obvious that rating is always bigger smaller than 5 while its smaller than 9,
but my point is  that syntax is wrong and Im not taking about logic of this code.

Comment: The `5 <` is not even needed here, since all cases where it is false have already been handled in the `if`. You can just do `if rating <= 5: ... elif rating <= 9: ...`